# Why is `infix` the default

Tags: swift, infix-notation

I'm reading about [advanced operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) in swift.

A basic function:

```
func add(a: Unicorn, b: Unicorn) -> Unicorn { return a + b }
add(u1, u2) // two unicorns are added
```

An infix operator:

```
func + (a: Unicorn, b: Unicorn) -> Unicorn { return a + b }
c = u1 + u2
```

postfix:

```
postfix func + (a: Unicorn) -> Unicorn { return a + 2 } // nonsense example
u1+
```

I don't understand how `infix` can be presumed to be the default. It doesn't look any different to me from a normal function declaration.

What is the rule here--is any single character a legal name for an infix operation? Does this mean single char functions are not otherwise allowed? Can *any* two-argument function in swift be called infix style?

Comment: Sometimes, to really understand something in a programming language, you need to go and learn yourself something about compilers. In this case, what a lexical analysis is and what a syntax analysis is.

Comment: For a really thorough knowledge, it'd be great to learn lexers and compilers. I'd love to take a compilers class. For now though, It's enough to know that if the function name is an operator and it has two args, `infix` is a derivable default. Custom operators require a definition, so this still works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't understand how infix can be presumed to be the default.

If you implement an operator with two arguments the compiler can be sure you want an infix operator, because only infix operators operate on two values.

If you implement an operator with one value the compiler isn't sure whether it is either an prefix or postfix operator and will complain.

Infix operators take two values, postfix and prefix only one.

> Does this mean single char functions are not otherwise allowed? Can any two-argument function in swift be called infix style?

No. A function that begins with any of these characters is an operator: /, =, -, +, !, *, %, <, >, &, |, ^, ?, or ~<sup>1</sup>. An operator can also consist of multiple characters, but it must begin with one of these characters.

Remember that a new operator must be declared first, for instance like this:

```
prefix operator / {}
prefix func / (a: Int) -> Int {
    return a / 42
}

/56
```

However this declaration won't work, because `a` is not one of the characters with which an operator must start:

```
prefix operator a {}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There are actually more characters. Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID410).

Comment: Great answer. I missed the fact that operators are a predefined [list of things](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID410), and that if you want new ones you have to [separately declare](https://medium.com/swift-programming/facets-of-swift-part-5-custom-operators-1080bc78ccc) them. Now everything makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, not all single characters can be infix operators. In general, the rule is that the characters allowed in identifiers (variables, method names etc) and characters allowed in operators are not the same.

For example, the characters allowed in operators are specified [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/operator)

More specifically, the first character in a token is the decisive one.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right I think the answer is: That you are overloading existing operator.

Let's say we would use a custom operator, I would need to declare prefix/infix/postfix

EDIT:
Found a better example on the internet:

Like:

```
infix operator **= { associativity right precedence 90 }
func **= (inout left: Double, right: Double) {
    left = left ** right
}
```